# Azure YAML build triggers all the time unexpectedly

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a few YAML pipeline definitions set up on Azure Pipelines with a Bitbucket repo - one for PRs, another for after a merge to develop, and one for live deployments. To have them triggered appropriately, I've added "pr:" section to the PR build, "triggger:" to the dev one and nothing in the live one, like that:

pr-pipeline.yml

```
name: 2.0$(Rev:.r)-pr

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  paths:
    include:
    - api
    exclude:
    - 'api/*.yml'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
...
```

dev-pipeline.yml

```
name: 2.0$(Rev:.r)

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  paths:
    include:
    - api
    exclude:
    - 'api/*.yml'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
...
```

live-pipeline.yml

```
name: $(versionNumber)

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
...
```

Now, when I push any changes to any feature branch (started from develop), they all trigger. With every push. Even if there are no PRs open and the changes go to a different branch (not develop). The description on Azure "Last Run" column says "Individual CI for feature/task-5". Any ideas what might be causing these spontaneous triggers?

I know YML triggers might be overriden in the pipeline settings on Azure, but it's not checked for any of them here. Is there another setting I'm missing? Or maybe there's a separate configuration on Bitbucket that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you gone through this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/63387238

Comment: I have, but it's not related with stages, variables or templates. In my case, all these pipelines are independent and the steps don't matter - they simply shouldn't start.