# can't use extends and stages together azure pipelines

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline, extends

I am trying to use a template in azure devops, because it is a template to make the build of a proyect with gradle and weblogic, but before doing that i need to create the build in the front and move it to the back, the problem with that is when i add the stages it throws an error Unexpected property extends
And it is not because of the version because without the steps it works normally

There is a correct option to do that, without changing the template?, i already tried many things but doesnt work, this is my code

```
trigger:
  - none

parameters:
  - name: deliveryTrain
    type: object
    default:
      continuousIntegration:
        build:
          - with: gradle
            configure:
              javaVersion: '1.8'
              gradleExtraOptionsLabo: 'clean build'
              workingDirectory: 'Gerencia_Tecnologia/salud-mensajeria_dinamica-back'
        artifact:
          with: 'artifactory'
          configure:
            artifactName: 'dinamica.md.ear'
      continuousDelivery:
        deployment:
          - environment: 'labo'
            platform:
              with: 'weblogic'
              configure:
                serviceConnection: 'lab-Salud-wl-12.2.1.4'
      continuousTesting:
        - environment: 'labo'
          cases:
            - type: performance
              with: 'jmeter'
              configure:
                repo:
                  name: 'Gerencia_Tecnologia/salud-mensajeria_dinamica-back-ml'
                  branch: 'feature/hu_comun_1707'
                performanceTestFiles: 'jmeter/test/test.jmx'
                performanceTestPercentilTest: '99'
                performanceTestResultFiles: 'jmeter/test/result.jtl'

stages:
  - stage: MensajeriaDinamicaFrontBuild
    displayName: 'MensajeriaDinamica-Front-build'
    jobs:
      - job: BuildFrontEnd
        displayName: 'Build Front Artifact'
        pool:
          name: 'linux-generic'
        steps:
          - checkout: front
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '12.16.1'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'
          - script: npm install -g @angular/cli@9.0.0
            displayName: 'Install Angular CLI'
          - script: |
              npm install &&
              ng build --aot --output-hashing=all --prod
            displayName: 'Built Front Artifact'
          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: 'Publish Front Artifact to dist carpet'
            inputs:
              targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist'
              artifact: 'front-artifact'
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: 'Copy files to ArtifactStagingDirectory'
            inputs:
              SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist'
              Contents: '**'  
              TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish front Artifact to ArtifactStagingDirectory'
            inputs:
              pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              artifactName: 'MensajeriaDinamicaFrontArtifact'  

      - job: CopyArtifactsToBack
        condition: succeeded('BuildFrontEnd')
        dependsOn: BuildFrontEnd
        displayName: 'Move Front Artifact to Back-End Repository'
        pool:
          name: 'linux-generic'
        steps:
            - checkout: back
            - script: |
                rm -r $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WAR_MensajeriaDinamica/WebContent/resultadosapp/* &&
                echo "Listing the deleted folders file:"
                ls -R $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WAR_MensajeriaDinamica/WebContent/resultadosapp
              displayName: 'cleaned back webcontent'
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
              inputs:
                artifactName: 'MensajeriaDinamicaFrontArtifact' 
                targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/WAR_MensajeriaDinamica/WebContent/resultadosapp/'
            - script: |
                echo "Listing the downloaded artifact:"
                ls -R $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WAR_MensajeriaDinamica/WebContent/resultadosapp
            - template: templates/gradle-weblogic.yaml@templates
                
      - job: UsingTemplate
        displayName: 'Usar plantilla de gradle weblogic'
        steps:
          - checkout: templates
          - script: |
              ls -R $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/templates
            displayName: 'List Files in Cloned Repositories'


resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: back
      type: git
      name: Gerencia_Tecnologia/salud-mensajeria_dinamica-back-ml
      ref: feature/hu_comun_1707
    - repository: front
      type: git
      name: Gerencia_Tecnologia/salud-mensajeria_dinamica-fr
      ref: feature/hu-comun-tablas
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: Gerencia_Tecnologia/ti-templates_pipelines-conf
      ref: master

extends:
  template: 'templates/gradle-weblogic.yaml@templates'
  parameters:
    deliveryTrain: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain }}
```

And this is the template used

```
variables:
- template: ../transversal/vars/vars-global.yaml

parameters:
- name: deliveryTrain
  type: object
- name: changeOrderHistoriasId
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: changeOrderApprover
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: changeOrderItemApproverBusiness
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: changeOrderRequester
  type: string
  default: ''

stages:
  - template: ../transversal/stages/continuous-integration.yaml
    parameters:
      continuousIntegration: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousIntegration }}
  
  - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.Reason'],'PullRequest') }}:
    - ${{ if parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousDelivery }}:
      - template: ../transversal/stages/approvals.yaml
        parameters:
          deployment: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousDelivery.deployment }}
              
      - template: ../transversal/stages/continuous-delivery.yaml
        parameters:
          continuousDelivery: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousDelivery }}
          artifact: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousIntegration.artifact }}
          changeOrderHistoriasId: ${{ parameters.changeOrderHistoriasId }}
          changeOrderApprover: ${{ parameters.changeOrderApprover }}
          changeOrderItemApproverBusiness: ${{ parameters.changeOrderItemApproverBusiness }}
          changeOrderRequester: ${{ parameters.changeOrderRequester }}
    
    - template: ../transversal/stages/continuous-testing.yaml
      ${{ each environment in parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousTesting }}:
        ${{ if or( and(contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/' ), eq( environment.environment, 'none') ), and( eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop' ), eq( environment.environment, 'dllo') ), and( contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release' ), eq( environment.environment, 'labo') ), and( eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master' ), eq( environment.environment, 'pdn') ), and( contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/' ), eq( environment.environment, 'dllo') )) }}:
          parameters:
            continuousTesting: ${{ environment.cases }}
  
    - ${{ if or(parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousDelivery, parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousTesting ) }}:
      - template: ../transversal/stages/post-delivery.yaml
        parameters:
          deliveryTrain: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain }}
```

Comment: FYI - Jobs aren't guaranteed to run on the same machine. So if you create an artifact in the _BuildFrontEnd_ job, it's not guaranteed to be there when the job _CopyArtifacts_ runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your YAML sample, I can reproduce the same issue.

[image]

I am afraid that the extends and the stages fields are not able to be defined at the same time in YAML Pipeline.

To meet your requirement, you can change to use **- template** field to use the YAML template and define the stages at the same time.

**Update1:**

Based on your YAML sample, you can use the following YAML Pipeline YAML code:

Main YAML:

```
trigger:
  - none

variables:
- template: ../transversal/vars/vars-global.yaml  

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: back
      type: git
      name: Gerencia_Tecnologia/salud-mensajeria_dinamica-back-ml
      ref: feature/hu_comun_1707
    - repository: front
      type: git
      name: Gerencia_Tecnologia/salud-mensajeria_dinamica-fr
      ref: feature/hu-comun-tablas
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: Gerencia_Tecnologia/ti-templates_pipelines-conf
      ref: master

parameters:
  - name: deliveryTrain
    type: object
    default:
      continuousIntegration:
        build:
          - with: gradle
            configure:
              javaVersion: '1.8'
              gradleExtraOptionsLabo: 'clean build'
              workingDirectory: 'Gerencia_Tecnologia/salud-mensajeria_dinamica-back'
        artifact:
          with: 'artifactory'
          configure:
            artifactName: 'dinamica.md.ear'
      continuousDelivery:
        deployment:
          - environment: 'labo'
            platform:
              with: 'weblogic'
              configure:
                serviceConnection: 'lab-Salud-wl-12.2.1.4'
      continuousTesting:
        - environment: 'labo'
          cases:
            - type: performance
              with: 'jmeter'
              configure:
                repo:
                  name: 'Gerencia_Tecnologia/salud-mensajeria_dinamica-back-ml'
                  branch: 'feature/hu_comun_1707'
                performanceTestFiles: 'jmeter/test/test.jmx'
                performanceTestPercentilTest: '99'
                performanceTestResultFiles: 'jmeter/test/result.jtl'

stages:
  - stage: MensajeriaDinamicaFrontBuild
    displayName: 'MensajeriaDinamica-Front-build'
    jobs:
      - job: BuildFrontEnd
        displayName: 'Build Front Artifact'
        pool:
          name: 'linux-generic'
        steps:
          - checkout: front
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '12.16.1'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'
          - script: npm install -g @angular/cli@9.0.0
            displayName: 'Install Angular CLI'
          - script: |
              npm install &&
              ng build --aot --output-hashing=all --prod
            displayName: 'Built Front Artifact'
          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: 'Publish Front Artifact to dist carpet'
            inputs:
              targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist'
              artifact: 'front-artifact'
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: 'Copy files to ArtifactStagingDirectory'
            inputs:
              SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist'
              Contents: '**'  
              TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish front Artifact to ArtifactStagingDirectory'
            inputs:
              pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              artifactName: 'MensajeriaDinamicaFrontArtifact'  

      - job: CopyArtifactsToBack
        condition: succeeded('BuildFrontEnd')
        dependsOn: BuildFrontEnd
        displayName: 'Move Front Artifact to Back-End Repository'
        pool:
          name: 'linux-generic'
        steps:
            - checkout: back
            - script: |
                rm -r $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WAR_MensajeriaDinamica/WebContent/resultadosapp/* &&
                echo "Listing the deleted folders file:"
                ls -R $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WAR_MensajeriaDinamica/WebContent/resultadosapp
              displayName: 'cleaned back webcontent'
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
              inputs:
                artifactName: 'MensajeriaDinamicaFrontArtifact' 
                targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/WAR_MensajeriaDinamica/WebContent/resultadosapp/'
            - script: |
                echo "Listing the downloaded artifact:"
                ls -R $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WAR_MensajeriaDinamica/WebContent/resultadosapp
            - template: templates/gradle-weblogic.yaml@templates
                
      - job: UsingTemplate
        displayName: 'Usar plantilla de gradle weblogic'
        steps:
          - checkout: templates
          - script: |
              ls -R $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/templates
            displayName: 'List Files in Cloned Repositories'




  - template: 'templates/gradle-weblogic.yaml@templates'
    parameters:
      deliveryTrain: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain }}
```

Template YAML:

```
parameters:
- name: deliveryTrain
  type: object
- name: changeOrderHistoriasId
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: changeOrderApprover
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: changeOrderItemApproverBusiness
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: changeOrderRequester
  type: string
  default: ''

stages:
  - template: ../transversal/stages/continuous-integration.yaml
    parameters:
      continuousIntegration: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousIntegration }}
  
  - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.Reason'],'PullRequest') }}:
    - ${{ if parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousDelivery }}:
      - template: ../transversal/stages/approvals.yaml
        parameters:
          deployment: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousDelivery.deployment }}
              
      - template: ../transversal/stages/continuous-delivery.yaml
        parameters:
          continuousDelivery: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousDelivery }}
          artifact: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousIntegration.artifact }}
          changeOrderHistoriasId: ${{ parameters.changeOrderHistoriasId }}
          changeOrderApprover: ${{ parameters.changeOrderApprover }}
          changeOrderItemApproverBusiness: ${{ parameters.changeOrderItemApproverBusiness }}
          changeOrderRequester: ${{ parameters.changeOrderRequester }}
    
    - template: ../transversal/stages/continuous-testing.yaml
      ${{ each environment in parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousTesting }}:
        ${{ if or( and(contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/' ), eq( environment.environment, 'none') ), and( eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop' ), eq( environment.environment, 'dllo') ), and( contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release' ), eq( environment.environment, 'labo') ), and( eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master' ), eq( environment.environment, 'pdn') ), and( contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/' ), eq( environment.environment, 'dllo') )) }}:
          parameters:
            continuousTesting: ${{ environment.cases }}
  
    - ${{ if or(parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousDelivery, parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousTesting ) }}:
      - template: ../transversal/stages/post-delivery.yaml
        parameters:
          deliveryTrain: ${{ parameters.deliveryTrain }}
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to the doc: [Template usage reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried using a template but it doesnt work, i think my only option is to talk with the creators of the template, or i dont know what to do

Comment: @JhonSerna  Please check the update in my answer. I have modified the YAML sample based on your yaml code. You don't need to change any code in Yaml template. Just need to change the code in the main yaml, And it will work as expected.

Comment: Already tried that, but i get a error

/templates/gradle-weblogic.yaml@templates (Line: 1, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'variables' /templates/gradle-weblogic.yaml@templates (Line: 20, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages'

Comment: And its no the template, i already tried the extends option without the stages and it work

Comment: @JhonSerna Test the sample again. And since you are defining the stages in the template, the variables field is not able to be defined at the root level in template yaml. Refer to this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912733/azure-pipelines-yaml-unexpected-value-variables You can change to define the variable in main YAML. Have updated the yaml sample in the answer

Comment: When you use the extend feature, it supports to defining the key word in the yaml root level. For example: triggers, variables.

Answer (score 0):

Templates can only be used to define stages, jobs, steps or variables. The *extends* feature is intended to build off an existing pipeline that already defines stages. You unfortunately can't define stages and extends at the same time.

It would appear that the author of your *templates* library has provided a template that accepts a `deliveryTrain` parameter. This parameter is custom to your organization and is a loosely defined YAML object that is interpreted by their template. Hard to say what the template is doing without access to it, but I'd assume that it's defining the stages based on the *continuous integration*, *continuous delivery* keywords. Based on what you've provided, it looks like this template generates a maven artifact and pushes it to a storage mechanism (artifactory).

My suggestion would be to view the expanded template to understand what it's doing:

1. In the Pipeline Editor, provide the YAML that uses their template
2. Choose 'Download Full YAML' from the ellipsis:

   [image]
3. Review the steps provided by the template and determine where your custom tasks should go.
4. Reach out to your template authors to determine if their template allows you to specify your additional steps.

For example,

```yaml
extends:
  template: /pipeline.yml@templates
  parameters:
    deliveryTrain:
       continuousIntegration:
         build:
         - with: gradle
           ...
         - with: customSteps
             steps: # custom defined steps
             - checkout: 'salud-mensajeria_dinamica-fr'
             - task: UseNode@1
                inputs:
                  version: '12.16.1'
             - script: |
                 npm install @angular/cli@9.0.0 &&
                 npm install &&
                 ng build --aot --output-hashing=all --prod &&
                 cp -r dist/. $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
               displayName: 'Built and Copied Front Artifact'
         artifact:
          with: 'artifactory'
          configure:
            artifactName: 'dinamica.md.ear'
       continuousDelivery:
         ...
       continuousTesting:
         ...
```

An example of a template that would support this, based on the above:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: continuousIntegration
  steps:

  - ${{ each item in parameters.deliveryTrain.continuousIntegration.build }}:
    - ${{ if eq(item.with, 'customSteps') }}:
      - ${{ insert }}: ${{ with.steps }}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer

Comment: Im gonna add the template to the question

Comment: I think my only option is to talk with te creators of the template, or i dont know if i can create 2 pipelines who are conected

Comment: If the answers helped you, please up-vote or accept :-)